# Is there a way to load the miniprofiler javascript over SSL

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I've included mini-profiler in my app.  It loads great on standard http pages, but over SSL I get the following warning

> page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://mydomain/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=xyz

Is there a setting or other type of configuration I can use to get this to load over HTTPS?